# Symfony2 dynamic route query params (sef) and more than 255 chars in url

Tags: php, url, search, filter, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to create search filters that vary depending on object category. I need to show all of them in URL, even if it takes more than 255 chars and, to be honest, I'm lost.

I found 2 working examples:
[PC componentes](https://www.pccomponentes.com/portatiles/1-tb/128-gb-ssd/2-celdas/2-en-1-convertibles/2-tb/256-gb/256-gb-ssd/3-celdas/32-gb/4-celdas/500-gb/6-celdas/64-gb-ssd/8-gb-ssd/blanco/con-bluetooth/gris/lector-de-tarjetas/negro/pc-para-gaming/plata/ultrabook/workstation)

[Idealista](https://www.idealista.com/venta-viviendas/alicante-alacant-alicante/con-precio-hasta_120000,precio-desde_60000,metros-cuadrados-mas-de_40,metros-cuadrados-menos-de_180,pisos,chalets,casas-de-pueblo,duplex,aticos,estudios,de-un-dormitorio,de-dos-dormitorios,de-tres-dormitorios,de-cuatro-cinco-habitaciones-o-mas/)

What I have done is to create 3 routes in order to pass an ad type, property type, state, locality and a district. The first 3 parameters are always required and in this cases I know exactly the params order:

```
tpl_search_adtype_type_state:
    path: /{adType}-{propertyType}-{state}/page-{page}
    defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Controller:action1, page: 1 }

tpl_search_adtype_type_state_locality:
    path: /{adType}-{propertyType}-{state}/{locality}/page-{page}
    defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Controller:action2, page: 1 }

tpl_search_adtype_type_state_locality_district:
    path: /{adType}-{propertyType}-{state}/{locality}/{district}/page-{page}
    defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Controller:action3, page: 1 }
```

An example route 1 would be: `/rent-houses-madrid/`
An example route 2 would be: `/rent-houses-madrid/madrid/`
An example route 3 would be: `/rent-houses-madrid/madrid/city-center/`

Now over these routes I need to add filter params like:

Route 1:

```
/rent-houses-madrid/min-price-100/max-price-5000/min-rooms-2/max-rooms-5/
```

But not all params should be there, another example would be:

```
/rent-houses-madrid/max-price-1000/min-rooms-2/min-toilets-2/
```

Any idea about how to achieve this in symfony2?

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried with multiple routes in order to pass an ad type, state, locality and district but I think it is not the best way and in this case I know exactly the order of params

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the post, thanks